# Change the model(sdk_gphone64_x86_64) and serial number(EMULATOR32X1X15X0) of the virtual device

Tags: android, android-studio, appium, appium-android, python-appium

Is it possible to **change the model(sdk_gphone64_x86_64) and serial number(EMULATOR32X1X15X0) of the virtual device** we create with Android Studio?

link image:
https://discuss.appium.io/uploads/default/original/2X/6/63baf58a29bd50f430fdb6f0909be100d0e2bc57.jpeg
https://discuss.appium.io/uploads/default/original/2X/3/33cd3f87b5b92b3eabec1ee941b21a4fefce2741.jpeg

I want to use multiple devices at the same time for the same application and to remain anonymous I want the devices to be different models.